# Alternative to for loops | How to check if word contains part of a different word

Tags: python, for-loop, set

If you check the code below i used for loops to check if in a set of words, one word is the suffix of another.

My question is, how can i replace the double for loop? The guy who wrote the task mentioned that there is a solution using algorithms (not sure what's that :/ )

```
def checkio(words):
    if len(words) == 1: return False
    else:
        for w1 in words:
            for w2 in words:
                if w1 == w2:
                    continue
                elif w1.endswith(w2) or w2.endswith(w1): return True
                else: return False

print checkio({"abc","cba","ba","a","c"}) # prints True in Komodo 
print checkio({"walk", "duckwalk"}) # prints True
```

Second question:
it appears that the current function doesn't work in every environment.
Can someone point out what i did wrong? It works on my Komodo IDE but won't work on chekio website.

here is a link to the task : **http://www.checkio.org/mission/end-of-other/**

Comment: Can you explain more what do you mean by " one word is the suffix of another." .. through examples?

Comment: @KhalilAmmour-خليلعمور , {"hello", "lo", "he"} == True, because 'lo' is found in the word 'hello' and is it's suffix.  Or like in the example at the bottom : "walk" is the ending of 'duckwalk'

Comment: So in my understanding, in a set of words you check if and only if there is at least one word in this set which is a "SUFFIX" of another word regardless which word is that(just any word in the set) ?

Comment: If your code is supposed to print `True` twice, you should make that clear in the body of the question.

Comment: @KhalilAmmour-خليلعمور, Yes, exactly.

Comment: Komodo must be weird (or something funny's happening with your indentation), since your current code returns `False` as soon as it finds a pair of words where 1 word isn't the suffix of the other. You need to de-indent the `else: return False` so that it's aligned with the outer `for`.

Comment: You can simplify your logic slightly by getting rid of the 1st `else` and changing the `elif` to `if`, since they're both preceded by `return`. Also, you're testing every combination twice. OTOH, that means you _may_ return `True` sooner than if you weren't doing the double test.

Comment: @PM2Ring, thanks for both of your comments. I added the second test for combination because of the inconsistency of the result. I thought that it's becase set is an unordered data type

Comment: Yes, `set` is unordered, but each time you iterate over a set you get the elements in the same order...  assuming you don't add or remove any elements in the mean time. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let Python generate all combinations to be checked:

```
import itertools

def checkio(data):
    return any((x.endswith(y) or y.endswith(x)) for x, y in itertools.combinations(data, 2))
```

And let Python test it:

```
assert checkio({"abc","cba","ba","a","c"}) == True
assert checkio({"walk", "duckwalk"}) == True
assert checkio({"aaa", "bbb"}) == False
```

Comment: thanks, that works beautifully. I'm still new to programming so i guess there are alot of useful modules i dont know yet, gonna read some documentation on it . :) thanks

Comment: @EugeneNosenko: Definitely check out itertools; there's some great stuff in there. And don't be _too_ concerned about importing standard modules: they load quickly & they're _guaranteed_ to always be available, although newer versions _may_ implement features not present in older versions.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a for loop version using `itertools.combinations()`:

```
def checkio(words):
    for w1, w2 in itertools.combinations(words, 2):
        if w1.endswith(w2) or w2.endswith(w1):
            return True
    return False

print checkio({"abc","cba","ba","a","c"}) # prints True in Komodo only :/
print checkio({"walk", "duckwalk"}) # prints True
print checkio({"a", "foo", "bar"}) # prints False
```

Giving:

```
True
True
False
```

If you print each iteration you will see how the `combinations()` function works, so for the last example you will see it try the following:

```
a - foo
a - bar
foo - bar
```

Answer (score 2):

Can use intersections and comprehensions:

```
def checkio(words):
    for w in words:
        ends = {w[i:] for i in range(1,len(w))}
        if len(words & ends) > 0:
            return True
    return False
```

Output:

```
>>> checkio({"walk", "duckwalk"})
True
>>> checkio({"walk", "duckbill"})
False
```

The way it works is as follows. Suppose that `words` contained the word 'scared'. When `w` is 'scared' the set of slices `ends` becomes {'cared', 'ared', 'red', 'e', 'd'}. & is Python's intersection operator. If any word is common to both `words` and `ends`, e.g. 'red', this intersection will be nonempty hence `len(words & ends) > 0` will be `True` -- which is then returned as the function value. If the code succeeds in looping through all words without encountering and for which `len(words & ends) > 0`, there are no examples of one word being a suffix of another in the list and `False` is thus returned.

Comment: Nice. You can simplify the return condition since the empty set is false-ish, i.e., `not set()` is `True`.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for your answer. I see that it works perfectly but i can't understand the logic behind this solution.(sorry i'm still a newbie) If you or someone would be so kind to elaborate on that i'd really appreciate it! thanks

Comment: @EugeneNosenko If w is, say "scared" then len(w) = 6 and the expressions like w[2:] return string slices (w[2:] returns 'ared', for example). The set comprehension in this case would return the set of strings {'cared', 'ared', 'red', 'ed', 'd'}. & is Python's set intersection operator so words & ends returns strings which are common to both sets. E.g. -- if 'red' was in the word list then in this case it would be included. Checking the length od the intersection checks if it is nonempty. If nonempty, return true. If none of the end sets have a nonempty intersection with words - return False

Comment: @PM 2Ring I've never been a fan of treating non-Booleans as Booleans in Python. It always strikes me as against the spirit of the language (c.f. "Explicit is better than implicit" and "Readability counts" from the Zen of Python). Ultimately it is a matter of taste.

Comment: Fair enough, re: the Booleans thing. OTOH, in this case it saves a method call, although I admit `len` is _very_ fast on native Python container types, since it's simply an attribute lookup.

Comment: @PM2Ring I didn't think about the method call overhead. If the set of words is huge it could potentially make a difference.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks guys, all of your comments and replies helped me to look at it dfferently. i think that this code is alot less bulky and clear and doesnt require module import

```
def checkio(words):
    for w1 in words:
        for w2 in words:
            if w1 != w2 and (w1.endswith(w2) or w2.endswith(w1)):
                return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 1):

Python's [str.endswith()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_endswith.htm) will do the work.

***Sample script:***

```
>>> a = 'hello'
>>> a.endswith('llo')
True
>>> a.endswith('ello')
True
>>> a.endswith('o')
True
>>> a.endswith('lo')
True
>>> a.endswith('ell')
False
```

***Wrapping to a function:***

```
import itertools
def checkio(words):

    words = [ w for w, s in itertools.product(words, words) if w != s and ( w.endswith(s) or s.endswith(w) ) ]
    return False if len(words) == 0 else True
```

***Sample output:*** [You can test it here:](https://repl.it/w9s/8)

```
checkio( {"hello", "lo", "he"} ) => True
checkio( {"hello", "la", "hellow", "cow"} ) => False
checkio( {"walk", "duckwalk"} ) => True
checkio( {"one"} ) => False
checkio( {"helicopter", "li", "he"} ) => False
```

Comment: Thanks, but the thing is i need the function to check an unknow input, meaning it should work with any set of words. plus im already using str.endswith().

Comment: Your function returns `True` if the random word that you pop out of `words` is a suffix of _every_ other word in `words`. That's not what the OP wants.

Comment: That's an improvement, but it's still not checking enough stuff. And there's no benefit in converting the set to a list. BTW, when you _do_ want to converting a set to a list you can do it with `list(some_set)`.

Comment: @PM2Ring I changed my approach in solving the problem, btw, thank you for suggestions!

Comment: Ok! That's looking a *lot* better, Ray. But you're calculating  `w.endswith(s) or s.endswith(w)` twice for each pair of (non-equal) words. One way to fix that is replace the first `w.endswith(s) or s.endswith(w)` with a simple `True`. Do you see why that would work?

Comment: @PM2Ring Okay, since it checks twice, giving `True` for every `w.endswith(s) or s.endswith(w)` is just the same. Btw, I just changed it to `w` since the function's return is based on the `len` of the list with `False` matches removed.  Thank you very much sir!